# Domain model representation of many to many relation with order

Tags: c#, oop, dns

I'm trying to understand how to represent in a Domain Model the following relation

**Table1**
PK_t1

**Table2**
PK_t2

**MMTable**
PK_t1
PK_t2
order

Do I need to create a separate Entity for this relation in order to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i personally wouldnt. i would use `IList<Entity2>`.

```
class Entity1
{
    public virtual IList<Entity2> Entity2s { get; set; }
}
```

maybe because its supported by NHibernate